# Remove consecutive "x" characters from the beginning of a field with Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a column called **Name** in a table called **Team**.  When the **Name** values begin with one or more consecutive "x" characters, I want those excluded, but keep any "x" which occurs later in the same string.

I have used ...

```
SELECT REPLACE(Name, 'x', '') FROM table
```

But that doesn't give me the result I want because it changes `xJammy Pricx` to `Jammy Pric`, and `xP-X Corp` to `P- Corp`.  I want to erase *only* the leading x characters.

For these sample values ...

```
xxxJames
xxxxxxxVikkie
XXXJohnny
xJakie
xJammy Pricx 
xP-X Corp
```

Result should be ...

```
James
Vikkie
Johnny
Jakie
Jammy Pricx
P-X Corp
```

Comment: Please mention the programming language you are using and add appropriate tag

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how to do what you want with plain Access SQL and standard VBA functions which can be used in a query.  So I think you will need a custom function for your query.  And in that case, a regular expression approach would be easy.

```sql
SELECT RegExpReplace([Name], '^[Xx]*', '')
FROM Team;
```

In the pattern, `^[Xx]*`, `^` matches the start of the string, `[Xx]` matches one `X` or `x` character, and `*` means zero or more matches of the previous character (`X` or `x`).

Add this function to a standard module.  If it's a new module, do not name the module `RegExpReplace`; `modRegExpReplace` would be OK.

```vb
Public Function RegExpReplace(ByVal varSource As Variant, _
        ByVal strPattern As String, _
        ByVal strReplace As String) As Variant

'version 2016-07-17

    Static re As Object
    Dim varOut As Variant

    If re Is Nothing Then
        Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        re.Global = True
        re.IgnoreCase = False
    End If
    re.Pattern = strPattern
    varOut = Null
    If Not IsNull(varSource) Then
        varOut = re.Replace(varSource, strReplace)
    End If
    RegExpReplace = varOut
End Function
```